# SSH connection failed to EC2 instance after Port change

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, port

I am working on an Amazon EC2 web server. I have changed default ssh port to 8083. After restarting the sshd service, I cannot access to the server using new port and old port. How can I resolve the problem to connect to my server again?

Answer (score 6):

You need to allow access to port 8803 in the EC2 instance security groups.

Check in the Amazon Ec2 Management Console under Network and Security.

Comment: Ugh, duh? Why do I keep forgetting this.